# How to remove logical duplicates from a dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a dataframe table where `C1` and `C2` are column names as below :

```
+-----|-----|
|C1   | C2  |
+-----|-----|
|a    |  b  |
|c    |  d  |
|b    |  a  |
+-----|-----|
```

I want the logical duplicates i.e (b,a) row  to be dropped from the above table.

I tried with self join but unable to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can *create a new column with the value of `C1` and `C2`*, *sort them* and use `dropDuplicates` to remove the duplicates (comments are provided for clarity)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df
  .withColumn("sortedCol", sort_array(array("C1", "C2")))  //creating a new sorted array column which contains the values of other columns
  .dropDuplicates("sortedCol")  //dropping duplicate columns which are logically same 
  .drop("sortedCol")    //removing the new column
  .show(false)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

With "except":

```
val df = List(
  ("a", "b"),
  ("c", "d"),
  ("b", "a")).toDF("C1", "C2")

df.except(df.where($"C1" > $"C2")).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+---+
|C1 |C2 |
+---+---+
|a  |b  |
|c  |d  |
+---+---+
```